# Is it circular to use L'Hospital's rule to find derivative?

Tags: calculus, limits

I was killing time by doing some random math on paper and came up with the idea of trying to use L'Hospital on the limit definition of the derivative. If I choose the function $f(x)=\ln x$ then I can do
$$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\ln(x+h) - \ln x}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\ln(\frac{x+h}{x})}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\ln(1 + \frac hx)}{h}$$ The numerator approaches $\ln 1=0$ and the denominator approaches $0$, so I take the derivative of both with respect to $h$.
$$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f'(1 + \frac hx)\cdot \frac 1x}{1}=
\frac 1x \cdot \lim_{h\to 0}f'(1+\frac hx)$$
$$f'(x)=\frac{f'(1)}{x}$$ This just so happens to match the truth, but I suspect that this is a flawed argument. Can you tell me specifically where any holes in the logic might be?

Comment: I like how you're using the derivative of a function to calculate its derivative.

Comment: It is definitely circular.  How do you find $\frac {d}{dh} \ln(1+\frac{h}{x})$ if you don't know how to take the derivative of the logarithm to begin with.  But since mathematics is consistent, since you know what the derivative is supposed to be you arrive at the correct answer.

Comment: Wait, I don't see why this is circular. Isn't line two happening because of the chain rule? the OP is calculating the derivative of any function $f$ for which $f(a/b)=f(a)-f(b)$, right? Where is my logic going wrong there?

Comment: Your argument isn’t flawed, but it isn’t useful either. That is: your argument is not proving anything (although it may be argued that it corroborates (i.e. it is empirical evidence) that l'Hôpital’s rule is consistent?). You have derived that $f’(x)=f’(1)/x$ by using the fact that $f’(x)$ exists around $1$ and that it has to be continuous at $x=1$ since you equated $\lim_{h\to0}f’(1+h/x)=f’(1)$ which implies, not only the existence of $f’(x)$ at $x=1$, but also its continuity. What are the premises that you are presupposing to assert those two facts?

Comment: I think random exploration like this is a good way to find new ideas

Comment: To reiterate, if you can show that $f(x)=\ln x$ is continuously differentiable at $x=1$ without using implicitily the fact that $f(x)=f’(1)/x$, then your proof of the fact that $f’(x)=f’(1)/x$ is totally legit, i.e. valid and not circular. But I highly doubt that you could assert anything about the existence of its derivative around $1$ (let alone its continuity) without explicitly deriving its form.

Comment: I find confusing the way you took the derivative of numerator. I’ve edited your attempt for clarity. This is how I would have done it:

$\frac{d}{dh}\left(\ln{(1+\frac{h}{x})}\right)=\frac{1}{1+\frac{h}{x}}\cdot (\frac{1}{x})=\frac{1}{x+h}$

The limit becomes $\lim_{h\to 0}{\frac{1}{x+h}}=\frac{1}{x}$

This is how you did it:

$\frac{d}{dh}\left(\ln{(1+\frac{h}{x})}\right)=\ln \prime(1+\frac hx)\cdot (\frac{1}{x})$

Then you went to deduce that $\lim_{h\to 0}{\ln\prime({1+\frac hx})}=\ln \prime (1)=1$ and used that to figure out that $\ln \prime(x)=\frac 1x$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument is **not** circular, but it is incomplete.  We need to assume the following properties of $f(x) = \log x$:

1. $f$ is differentiable in a neighborhood of $1$.
2. $f$ obeys the property $f(a) + f(b) = f(ab)$ for all $a, b > 0$.
3. $f$ permits $\lim_{x \to a} f'(g(x)) = f'(\lim_{x \to a}g(x))$; that is, the derivative of $f$ may be interchanged with the limit for a suitable function $g$.

Then,

$$\begin{align*}
f'(x) &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} &&\text{(definition)} \\
&= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(1 + \frac{h}{x})}{h} && \text{(property 2)} \\
&= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{d}{dh}[f(1 + \frac{h}{x})]}{1} && \text{(property 1 + L'Hopital's rule)} \\
&= \lim_{h \to 0} f'\left(1 + \frac{h}{x}\right) \cdot \frac{d}{dh}\left[1 + \frac{h}{x}\right] && \text{(chain rule)} \\
&= \frac{1}{x} \lim_{h \to 0} f'\left(1 + \frac{h}{x}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{x} f'\left( \lim_{h \to 0} 1 + \frac{h}{x} \right) && \text{(property 3)} \\
& \frac{f'(1)}{x}.
\end{align*}$$

Then this calculation shows that $f'(x)$ is proportional to some constant times $1/x$, and that this constant is the value of the derivative at $1$.  So we are not done; we need to ascertain this value.

Comment: Could you expand a bit on (3)? Is this satisfied i.e. for all $C^\infty$ functions or what makes up the classes of functions satisfying (3)? I know it's a bit off topic but the question is mostly asked to find out more interesting stuff anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's rather useless because you'll use the derivative you want to find.
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{\ln(1+\frac{h}{x})}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{\dfrac{1}{x}\times\dfrac{1}{1+\frac{h}{x}}}{1}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{x}\times\frac{x}{x+h}=\frac{1}{x}.$$
If you want to calculate the derivative of $\ln$ using the formula, you can try the idea
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{h}\ln\left(1+\frac{h}{x}\right)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\ln\left(\left(1+\frac{h}{x}\right)^\frac{1}{h}\right)$$
I guess you can continue from here.

Comment: If you substitute $u=1/h$ where $h\to0$ you don’t get the limit $u\to+\infty$. That would be the case if the limit were $h\to0^+$. So, to be precise, the limit $u\to-\infty$ should also be studied. Though, it is well known that both of these limits lead to the same value.

Answer (score -1):

The holes in your logic is that you are using things that you have been given to prove. Consider a simple example below which is not very different from yours ;

Prove that Elephant $= 1$

Proof : Elephant = 1

Hence, Elephant$ –1 = 0$

Now adding $1$ both sides, we have ;

Elephant$ = 1$ . Hence proved.

Certainly there are non-circular ways to derive this.